# How to put 2 logos in baposter style?

Tags: floats, positioning, baposter

I need a big help about how to position 1 logo to the left and one logo to the right in a poster I'm currently working on. I'm using baposter style.

This is the code I actually use, where the 2 logo are put one on top each other to the right. How can I change this? I've tried many rough changes, but none of them worked. Thank you very much in advance.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}   
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
\leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}
\newenvironment{boenumerate}
{\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf\theenumi.}}
{\end{enumerate}}
\newlength\Colsep
\setlength\Colsep{1pt}

\typeout{Poster rendering started}

 %%% Setting Background Image 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \background{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
 \draw (current page.north west)+(-2em,2em) node[anchor=north west]
 {\includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{background}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }

 \begin{document}
 \definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.45}
 \definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.25}
 \definecolor{redorange}{cmyk}{0,0.91,0.50,0.40}
 \definecolor{apricot}{cmyk}{0,0.34,0.19,0.20}
 \definecolor{beige}{rgb}{0.96, 0.96, 0.86}
 \definecolor{blond}{rgb}{0.98, 0.94, 0.75}
 \definecolor{buff}{rgb}{0.94, 0.86, 0.51}
 \definecolor{palegoldenrod}{rgb}{0.93, 0.91, 0.67}
 \begin{poster}
 {
 grid=false,
 headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
 colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
 bgColorOne=palegoldenrod, % Background color for the gradient on the 
 left side of the poster
 bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right 
 side of the poster
 borderColor=redorange, % Border color
 headerColorOne=apricot, % Background color for the header in the 
 content boxes (left side)
 headerColorTwo=apricot, % Background color for the header in the 
 content boxes (right side)
 headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the 
 content boxes
 boxColorOne=beige, % Background color of the content boxes
 textborder=rounded, %rectangle, % Format of the border around content 
 boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, 
 roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
 eyecatcher=false, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the 
 title and move the title left
 headerheight=0.11\textheight, % Height of the header
 headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box 
 headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft 
 or rounded
 headershade=plain,
 headerfont=\Large\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the 
 headers of content boxes
 %textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph 
 indentation
 linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
 }
 {}
 %
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------
 --------------------
 %   TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------
 --------------------
 %
 {\textsf %Sans Serif
 {Poster Title
 }
 } 
 {\sf\vspace{0.005em}\\
 Authors
 \vspace{0.1em} \\
 \small{University
 \vspace{0.2em}\leavevmode \\
 Department
 \vspace{0.2em} \\
 email}
 }
 {
 \twoobjects
        {\includegraphics[width=10em,height=4em]{logo1}} % i want this 
 on the left
        {\includegraphics[width=10em,height=4em]{logo2}} %i want this 
 on the right
 }
 \end{document}
```

Comment: change eyecatcher=false to eyecatcher=true

Comment: I had trouble putting the logo's like in the example of Biki Teron. It turned out that I put a newline behind the option box of `\begin{poster}`. You should NOT put a newline there.

Answer (score 1):

This i made for A4 size, you can change to it according to your desire and some modification

```
 \documentclass[portrait,final,a4paper,fontscale=1]{baposter}

 \usepackage{lipsum,float}

 \usepackage{lmodern}

 \begin{document}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%% Here starts the poster
 %%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %%% Format it to your taste with the options
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % Define some colors

 %%
 \begin{poster}%
   % Poster Options
   {
   % Show grid to help with alignment
   grid=false,
   % Column spacing
   colspacing=1em,
   % Color style
   bgColorOne=white,
   bgColorTwo=white,
   borderColor=blue,
   headerColorOne=black,
   headerColorTwo=blue,
   headerFontColor=white,
   boxColorOne=white,
   boxColorTwo=blue,
   % Format of textbox
   textborder=roundedleft,
   % Format of text header
   eyecatcher=true,
   headerborder=closed,
   headerheight=0.1\textheight,
 %  textfont=\sc, An example of changing the text font
   headershape=roundedright,
   headershade=shadelr,
   headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
   textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}},
   boxshade=plain,
 %  background=shade-tb,
   background=plain,
   linewidth=2pt
   }
   % Eye Catcher
   {\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-a}} 
   % Title
   {\bf\textsc{Title of the poster}\vspace{0.5em}}
   % Authors
   {\textsc{\{ Author \}}}
   % University logo
   {% The makebox allows the title to flow into the logo, this is a hack because of the L shaped logo.
     \includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-b}
   }


 \end{poster}

 \end{document}
```

[image]